# How to override Itemstyle-width of BoundField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview, width

I created and use a class that inherits from BoundField. I want to add 'Description' column to my grid with minimum 300px but when I set Itemstyle-width(and headerstyle-width) to 300px it works in IE7 and Chrome but not in dumb IE8. I checked generated html and the only way to make it work in IE8 is to set 'min-width' instead 'width'.

I know I can use TemplateField instead or use ItemStyle-css attribute but I don't think it is good way cause I'd like to be able to set BoundField's widths easily.

Is there any solution to override ItemStyle-width(and Headerstyle-width) attribute so it will add/set width and ALSO min-width to TD element?

Thanks,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
ItemStyle-Width="300px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"
```

in the BoundField tag

Comment: I still want to wrap text in column but just set fixed width. I tried this and it added 'width: 300px; white-space: nowrap;' but column had 2758px width. However, it works in IE7 so I guess with max-width:300px it would work in IE8 as well, but can't find the way to set it without using css class.